# Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component without hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, navbar

I am getting the error above (Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component) without using any hooks, all i've done is try to make a navbar, which normally doesnt give me any issues. I have given my app.js code below.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
        <navbar />
    </Router> 
  );
}

export default App;
```

Now my Navbar component file.

```
import React from 'react';
import {  Link } from "react-router-dom";

const navbar= () =>{
  return (
  <div>
    <li>
      <Link to="/">Dogs</Link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Link to="/cats">Cats</Link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Link to="/sheep">Sheep</Link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Link to="/goats">Goats</Link>
    </li>
  </div>
  );
}
export default navbar;
```

Finally my dependencies

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.15.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
    "build": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if related but you are using `Link` from react-router-dom without having it as a dependency. Have you installed it ? Or it is part of react-scripts ?
Another issue is that a component must be capitalized thus `navbar` should be `Navbar`

Comment: Thanks for the tips! i am pretty new to reactjs. I found that this error occurs when I import Link or Router from the react-dom-router. I added as a dependency but still no help.